# Value of a variable that i did not initialize

Tags: c++

I have this exercise where i don't understand the method float set(void).So, at first A::v is initialized as a unknown number(1234 for example) but after  A::v = v + 1.0.

The result should be A::v= 1234 + 1.0.

It isn't,instead it is A::v=1.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    float v;
    float set(void) {
        A::v = v + 1.0;
        return A::v;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    cout<<a.set()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The behaviour of undefined behaviour is undefined, I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer.I'm sorry

Comment: You shouldn't *expect* anything, if your program has UB. It could print `hello world` as well.

Comment: Sorry i don't know what UB is.

Comment: It's possible as you can see that the memory contains zeroes. But you cannot rely on it. When you switch to a non-debug build it may contain "garbage" (random data that was left there).

Comment: UB (undefined behavior) means you are doing something that is not defined; and the result of such a thing can by anything. Here you are defining a variable and you are NOT initializing it. So it can theoretically have any value.

Comment: can you send us your output?

Comment: Just a tip: if you insist on using argument names that are the same as data members, the usual convention is to use `this->` to disambiguate, rather than `A::`. So `this->v += 1.0;`. Better still, use different names: `float set(float f) { v += f; return f; }`

Comment: Alright thanks E.van Putten.So it should have any value but after A::v=v+1,A::v=1 always and everytime.I don't know why.

Comment: The expectet output of the exercise is 3 (everytime).I have added some couts to see what is happening to the variable.So before the sum with 1,A::v=5.1848e-044 and after the sum A::v=1

Comment: I have edited the post and simplified the code,leaving only the bit that matters.Why is A::v always 1 and not a random value?

Comment: @AndreiM it's about the position of that variable in your memory. if you have clean memory you will get it 0, if that part of memory had a value you will get that

Comment: @ MH Alikhani I see thank you.

Comment: @E.vanPutten Using an indeterminate value is even worse than "could be any value". Anything at all could happen, and one real-world thing would be a crash due to trap representation access.

Comment: @AndreiM the reason you see 1 is that you are adding a relative big number (1) to an extremely small number (the unitialized value was `5.2e-44` you said) . The floating point format does not handle such cases well.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for that (I'm aware of that). Of course I'd also advice to initialize the variable etc, but I'm afraid that's not the answer the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question why the value is always 1:
well, it isn't. It depends on whatever is left there in memory. You have seen a few examples where the uninitialized float value is so small that adding 1.0 to it yields something close to 1.0

But that certainly may not always be the case!
Initialize the variable to 0.

Some further reading:
[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

You just not initialize value inside class.
When you allocate space on stack, values are random junk.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    float v = 1234.0; //You must initialize it with 1234 if you want result 1235
    float set(void) {
        /*A::v*/ v = v + 1.0;
        return A::v;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a; //Initializing space on stack, uninitialized values are always, 0x00, 0xcd or trash from other functions.
    cout<<a.set()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the whole exercise,https://www.codepile.net/pile/6Zq87DGk    .It wants me to guess the output.

Comment: Yes yes. I think he already knows that, but he's looking for an explanation why `v` becomes 1.0 even though it had a 'strange' value. May be the result of adding floating point values together that are far apart in terms of the exponent.